# dimension of an image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$dim (img T)+dim (ker T)=dim (V)$
is the following a proof or enough to ensure that the formula is correct?

let suppose we have a linear space V and a transformation from $V$ to$V$:
then if we look at the $v$ in $img T$ it can be written as a combination of $v_1$ to $v_{n-k}$ -a basis of $V$ + the sum of all combinations of the transformation on the basis of $ker(T)$.
in addition $v_1$ to $v_{n-k}$ can be written as ($a_i \in V$) $T(a_1)$ to $T(a_{n-k})$ -basis of $img T$ than $ker T = a_{n-k+1}...a_n :                                          
v = v_1+...v_{n-k} + T(a_{n-k+1})+...T(a_n) $
$dim (img T)$is obviously $n-k$ and $ker T$ is $k$
than we can see that $dim (ker T) +dim (img T) = dim (V)$

Comment: Well, the proof is *something like this*, but it's far from being correct..

Comment: You might want to add the hypotheses to the theorem, namely that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, and that $T$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to $V$. Also: avoid run-on sentences. See if you can write this as a sequence of short sentences with only one verb each, and no subordinate clauses.